# Does it make sense to define an Interface for internal use where we know needs with change?

Tags: c#, interface

I am in the designing stage of a new project for internal use - the software will never be "shipped". I know with absolute certainty that we will add more functionality to the project going forward. If I were to wait then the project will never get done. I am approaching the project by designing Interfaces. I want to use interfaces in the code so I can check classes for that type and do certain things. I also want to perform operations on all classes of a certain Interface. There will be certain Interfaces where classes will have different logic to achieve the result. Interfaces make sense for this.

My two questions:

1. Everybody seems to say that your interface needs to be stable. If you need to add additional capabilities later on what does one typically do? Inherit a base interface and add on?
2. There are certain situations where (for now) an Interface will only be implemented by one class. In this case does it still make sense to use an Interface?

Comment: There´s no general answer to this question, as it highly depends on what you plan to add in the future, who uses the API and also your personal preferences.

Comment: Howeveryou should not make assumptions of kind "I am sure this will never happen". Having created software for several years I can assure you that "everything that might will change some day". It´s nearly impossible to foresee how your API will be used in the future. So you should be open to extension, but closed to modification ([open-closed-prinicple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open–closed_principle))

Comment: Open-closed-principal makes a lot of sense. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer to 1st question:

It should be stable, yes. To achieve this create very focused interfaces. This means 1 interface should describe very limited function / has only few property.
Then to have a complex interface: merge them into a combined interface.

Forexample `ITree` and `IPlant` is a very wide description and should not exists. `IEverGreen` and `IDeciduous` are just a bit better. What you should look is smaller parts like:

```
IHaveRoot {}
IRePlantable {}
IHaveLeaves{}
```

and then:

```
ILeafAndRootOwner : IHaveRoot, IHaveLeaves
```

### Answer to 2nd question:

It makes sense because you leave an open possibility for [Decorator Pattern](https://code-maze.com/decorator-design-pattern/) or to mark the existing implementation to obsolete while defining a new. And all other .cs files that references the interface doesn't have to change!

Answer (score 0):

> Everybody seems to say that your interface needs to be stable. If you need to add additional capabilities later on what does one typically do? Inherit a base interface and add on?

If components which inherit a given interface are not used for an API (meaning that for e.g. a plugin must inherit this interface to communicate with your application) then modifying the interface shouldn't be a problem

In my case if I need to extend my in-house plugins without breaking compatibility of customer plugins (both of which share the same interface to work) I'd do the following:
 - Create an extending interface
 - Inherit the extending interface in the plugin class

> There are certain situations where (for now) an Interface will only be implemented by one class. In this case does it still make sense to use an Interface?

You do not need an interface for everything, that is for sure; however, planing ahead what you might want to extend in the future or unit test will tell you where you definitely need one. For example you would decouple your application from specific dependencies by replacing them with interfaces and injecting the required implementations using [DI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

---

All in all, just like [@Himbrombeere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2528063/himbrombeere) says: it depends on what you are trying to achieve and you should be prepared for change in your software.

If you are talking about a simple tool which, for e.g. only reads a text file and let's say counts the words, then putting in a lot of effort in it doesn't make sense.